# Can´t get custom attribute on WooCommerce product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try to save custom meta data after creating an order in WooCommerce. I try it with the `woocommerce_new_order_item` hook and in general it works. But I need to store a custom attribute from the ordered product..but I can´t get it.

What I tried:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order_item','add_basic_meta_for_new_quote',10,3); // add extra order metas

function add_basic_meta_for_new_quote($item_id, $values, $cart_item_key)
{
    $angebotstext = get_post_meta($item_id, 'angebotstext', false);
    wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'angebotstext', $angebotstext);
}
```

or

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order_item','add_basic_meta_for_new_quote',10,3); // add extra order metas

function add_basic_meta_for_new_quote($item_id, $values, $cart_item_key)
{
    global $product;
    $angebotstext = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_angebotstext' );
    wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'angebotstext', $angebotstext);
}
```

The attribute is saved here:

[image]

... and the result for `meta_value` is always empty, NULL or `a:0:{}`

Do you have any idea?

-----EDIT----

It worked with this way:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_new_order_item','add_basic_meta_for_new_quote',10,3); // add extra order metas

function add_basic_meta_for_new_quote($item_id, $item, $order_id )
{

    if ($order_id) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  }

    # Iterating through each order items (WC_Order_Item_Product objects in WC 3+)
    if ($order) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values ) {

            // Product_id
            $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id();

            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            $angebotstext = $product->get_attribute('Angebotstext');
            if ( !empty($angebotstext) && $angebotstext != NULL ) {
                wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Angebotstext' , $angebotstext);
      }
        }
  }
}
```

BUT: This code adds my custom attribute two times as meta.... why that?

Comment: Why you don't try to get the attributes first then update the order as a normal wp post with "update_post_meta()"? so the value will be saved a custom field inside the order page and it will be easy to access whenever you want.

Comment: Do you have an example how I could do this?

Comment: By the way: I edited my answer... there is another issue... :/

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) is usually caused by a fatal error of PHP code exaclty on this ajax function (ywraq_submit_default_form line 1 as the logs are showing).
In a different world, this might be the reason why your code couldn't do the entire task because when it reached the function (ywraq_submit_default_form ). I may need more logs to check on this, but I believe you need to check your code on this function "ywraq_submit_default_form" as it's the one has an error.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Please check my edited code. Now the 500 is gone... but: This code adds my custom attribute two times as meta.... why that? 

Comment: get_items is returning an array that has more than 1 product, therefor the "foreach" will create a loop that which will update your order as many time as the number of products inside the order if your order has 2 product the "foreach" loop will run your code 2 times.

Comment: How I could prevent to create the second one with the same attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is if the order contains multiple products, so you're going to face the issue of multiple updates for the same order.

To avoid that or to choose to deal with it the right way, here are some ideas:

**To make this works for multiple products:**
Changed this part:

```
wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Angebotstext _'.$product_id , $angebotstext);
```

This will add a new custom meta for each product by adding the product ID at the end of each meta_key and the meta_value will be the product unique value for that attribute.
so you're going to find this custom fields on the order page:

- Angebotstext_123 = product attribute.
- Angebotstext_485 = product
- attribute. Angebotstext_951 = product attribute.

  the '123', '485' are the product id and the meta value for that meta_key will be that product attribute.

**To prevent it from updating multiple times:**

```
if ($order) {
     $angebotstext ='';
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values ) {

            // Product_id
            $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id();

            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            $angebotstext = $product->get_attribute('Angebotstext');
            $prev_angebotstext = $angebotstext;
            if ( !empty($angebotstext) && $angebotstext != NULL && $angebotstext != $prev_angebotstext ) {
                wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Angebotstext' , $angebotstext);
      }
        }
  }
```

"$prev_angebotstext" is the previous item attribute.

```
if ( !empty($angebotstext) && $angebotstext != NULL && $angebotstext != $prev_angebotstext )
```

This condition will check if the current product attribute is equal to the previous product attribute, if yes it will not update the order again.

Thank you!

Comment: Many thanks. What if I´m just using `wc_update_order_item_meta` instead of `wc_add_order_item_meta` ? I just tried it and it works! It creates only once :-) Would this works without other effects?

Comment: wc_update_order_item_meta will overwrite the existing value of the previously placed attribute. So by adding the condition to check if it's the same attribute you don't have to do this. Or you can delete the foreach and use this code below:

Comment: `if ($order) {
  $order_items = $order->get_items()
            // get the id of the first product on the order
            $product_id = $order_items[0]->get_product_id();
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            $angebotstext = $product->get_attribute('Angebotstext');
            if ( !empty($angebotstext) && $angebotstext != NULL ) {
                wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Angebotstext' , $angebotstext);
           }
        
  }`